# Equations of elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, finite-fields

First part of question I have asked on mathoverflow already: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467088/explict-form-of-the-equation-of-elliptic-curve

1) Let $E(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$ is elliptic curve with #$E(\mathbb{F}_{q^2}) =q^2 + q + 1$.
Can we write equation of this curve (something curve with same number points) in the explicit form? It will be interesting to get answer for infinetely family of $q$.

2) Let $E(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})$ is elliptic curve with #$E(\mathbb{F}_{2^n}) =2^n + 1$.
Can we write equation of this curve in the explicit form?

Comment: -1 The question is not precise as stated. Are the elliptic curves requested unique? Should your elliptic curve be originally defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ and then be reduced modulo every prime? Also it is not appreciated to doublepost here and on math.exchange within such a short-time period. I will upvote as soon as you improve the question, though.

Comment: @Marc Palm I'm sorry I meant something as next example: elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + x$ over $F_q$ has $q + 1$ points where $q = 4k +3$

Answer (score 6):

For (2), you'll need the coefficients of your equation to depend on $n$. More generally, if $E$ is defined over $q$ for any prime power $q$, for example $q=2^k$, and if $\#E(F_{q^n})=q^n+1$, then $\#E(F_{q^{2n}})=q^{2n}+2q^n+1$. So your formula in (2) can't hold for both $n$ and $2n$. For (1), the example you give in your comment has CM and you're choosing the inert (hence supersingular) primes. So for (1) you might try taking CM curves defined over some quadratic (or larger) extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ and reducing modulo ss primes of norm $q^2$. I don't know if that will work, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Curve $E$ with equation $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ has $p+1$ rational points over $\mathbb{F}_p$ when $p = 5$ (mod $6$). Let $q = p^n$. $|E(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})| = q^2 \pm 2q +1$.

Let $\zeta_6$ is generator of $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^*/\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^{*6}$.

Consider curve $E'$ with equation $y^2 = x^3 + \zeta^k$.

As it write in "Constructing supersingular elliptic curves" of Reinier Broker(http://www.math.brown.edu/~reinier/supersingular.pdf) $|E'(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})| = q^2 \pm q +1 $ when $k = 1$ and $|E'(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})| = q^2 \mp q +1 $ if $k = 2$.